# What is the best way to switch between connections to databases in java?

Tags: java, jdbc

I am developing an application in java, which must be constantly executing queries to a remote database, but, in the event that such connection fails, the same queries must be executed on a local sqlite database.
I have tried this way:

```
public static Connection connect() {
        Connection c = null;
        try {
            Class.forName("com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver");
            c = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://192.168.1.30/database", "root", "");
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.CommunicationsException e) {
            //Here I get the connection to sqlite in case of exception
            c = SQLiteDb.sqliteInit();
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return c;

    }
```

Is there another cleaner way to handle these cases?

Answer (score 1):

First of all you should use connection pool, otherwise every operation will create a new connection which is super expensive.
There are many connection pools available for Java. For example, Hikari provides a pretty good connection pool, there are also C3P0 and DBCP.

Now, there is an abstraction called Data Source that might be used depending on the infrastructure you use.

I don't suggest using plain JDBC since its low level and error prone.
Take a look at JOOQ or MyBatis.

Now, to address your requirement for the fallback you can keep two data sources with connection pools and everything and organize the flow in a way that if the call to mysql fails - work with sql lite. However note, that if mysql is down, probably it doesn't make sense to call it every time, maybe its trying to recuperate.

Take a look at Circuit Breaker pattern for example, it will address this issue.

Other than that, I feel like this question is too broad, SO is more geared towards very specific technical questions. The answers help to overcome a concrete technical difficulty. if you come up with something like this, feel free to ask :)